# three20 App crashes after some view changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20

first, i followed this tutorial: [three20 github tutorial](http://three20.info/tutorials/github/page/2)

i have a memory management problem i think, which crashes my application.

i think, `_properties` in my postsModel crashes my application.

the first time i launch my application and changing view to my `postsTableViewController`  works quite fine. i created a TTLauncherView, changing back to this viewcontroller crashes my app.

here now some code of my postsModel

```
// .h
@interface postsModel : TTURLRequestModel {
     NSMutableArray *_properties;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly)NSMutableArray *properties;

// .m
@synthesize properties = _properties;   
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
     TTURLDataResponse* response = request.response;
     NSString* responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: response.data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSDictionary *json =  [responseBody JSONValue];
     TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(responseBody);

     NSMutableArray *resultSet = [json objectForKey:@"posts"];
     TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_properties);
     _properties = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultSet];
     TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(resultSet);

     [super requestDidFinishLoad:request];
}


- (void)dealloc {
     TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_properties);

     [super dealloc];
}
```

removing  the tt_release of my _properties stops crashing the application by going back from this view to the Launcher view, but clicking on my TableView again, crashes the application again.

its a bit difficult to write down for me, because its quite a lot of code. i can also provide my app as a .zip file if it helps, its very basic right now.

thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the bug is a common one. Change:

```
_properties = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultSet];
```

To:

```
_properties = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultSet] retain];
```

Or make the property retaining and use:

```
self.properties = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultSet];
```

Comment: has no effect to my crash problem :(

Comment: Well, look for similar mistakes in other parts of your code then. This could certainly lead to crashes.

Comment: is there no way to find the position where my application crashes ? debugger is not really helpful

Comment: What do you see in the debugger? What if you enable NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: thanks! not retaining or using the setter method for my properties object was my main bug. with fixing this, it was easy to find another memory leak i created by releasing a already released object. now its working perfectly.